# 2 APs over Powerline Network within same IP subnet cannot see eachother?

Tags: networking, routing, dhcp, subnet, powerline-networking

I am having issues setting up my home network using powerline adapters.

**My Setup**

I have a Gateway, a Router, 3 Powerline ethernet adapters, and a Powerline Wifi Unit (TP-Link TLWPA4220).

All of the Powerline adapters and the wifi unit are on the same Powerline network. I have confirmed this.

I have the Gateway outputting from a single LAN port into the Powerline network. On one ethernet adapter, I have attached the Router. The Powerline Wifi unit is plugged in at a different location.

- The Router and Wifi Unit have the exact same settings for the wireless security and SSID.
- The Gateway is the primary DHCP supplier.
- The Router is set to Bridge Mode to stop it trying to create it's own subnet.
- I do not know how to change the Wifi Unit to bridge mode as there is really no good documentation. The best I can do is set it's IP to be within the subnet created by the Gateway.
- I can access the internet from both access points.
- The Gateway has the IP 192.168.1.254
- The Router has a reserved IP in the Gateway set for 192.168.1.253
- The Wifi Unit also has a reserved IP in the Gateway set for 192.168.1.252

**My Problem**

Although the Router and Wifi Unit are on the same subnet, which is connected to the same LAN port on the Gateway, they cannot see eachother.

First off, only the router is shown as being connected to the Gateway. The Wifi Unit doesn't exist according to the Gateway.

Second, if I have my phone connected to the Wifi Unit, and my computer connected to the Router, I cannot ping between them. They are not seen by eachother. However, the Gateway recognizes that they are both connected.

This leads me to believe that something is creating a different network and I can't see it for some reason.

Does anyone have any advice on how I should troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the TLWPA4220 and the other power-line network adapters (specifically the one attached to the router) are all on the same electrical circuit in the house?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes. Mainly because they (the powerline adapters) all see eachother and I can use the internet from either access point.

Comment: So (just to clarify) the WiFi powerline adapter can see the other 2 powerline adapters?   And moving the Wifi PL adapter to where a known-working AP adapter is, doesn't help?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am not at home to test moving it or not, but from what I remember seeing last night, the non-wifi units see EVERY powerline adapter on the network. The Wifi unit sees the Gateway-Linked ethernet adapter, but not the one linked to the router.

Could that be what's causing the issue? It simply can't go into the gateway and back out? Or through the gateway-adapter and into the router-adapter?

Comment: Why Gateway and router? Which one is connected to the Internet? What is the other doing? To narrow it down check if the Powerline connection is the Problem or if there is an IP Problem. You can check that by replacing Powerline Connections with cabled connection.